# What's MongoDB hash's size?

Tags: mongodb, hash, nosql

I need to know what is size of the hash of MongoDB. Can't find it on wikipedia or official site.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, I suggest asking the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user

Comment: Found out that MongoDB client show me 24-byte hex string, but drivers convert it to 12-byte binary string o_O. How can I convert 24-byte HEX to 12-byte BIN???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB uses 12-byte binary value (an ObjectId) -- it can be converted to 24-byte hex string.

Answer (score 3):

An ObjectId, the default value for the _id field, is a 12-byte value; it is not a hash nor a string -- it is stored as binary value. Many drivers will show it as a hex string, so it can be easily printed.

It is comprised of a timestamp (in secs), a host id, process id and counter; this means that it is increasing over time of creation, and encodes the time of creation (insertion).

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

Most drivers have helper methods to convert to and from the hex string representation, as well as creating one based on just the parts you are interested in -- i.e. a timestamp you might use for a range query. You can also easily extract the timestamp portion.